# how can i set the Tag value For multiple buttons in a single Cell in tableView in ios

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

in my project i have 5 row in a TableView each cell having four button totally i have 20 buttons for this my requirement is i want set tag value for Each buttons like

```
in First Cell -- 1 for btn1, 2 for btn2, 3 for btn3, 4 for btn4
   Second Cell-- 5 for btn5, 6 for btn6, 7 for btn7, 8 for btn8
```

[image]

like all Five Cells i need set a tag Value like this

**Note: When i scroll the TableView it not changing the tag Value**

i have set the tag value like this inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath Delegate Method

```
UIButton *btnLeftW,*btnLeft,*btnRight,*btnRightW;

btnLeftW=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:90];
btnLeft=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:91];
btnRight=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:92];
btnRightW=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:93];

 btnLeftW.tag=indexPath.row;
 btnLeft.tag=indexPath.row;
 btnRight.tag=indexPath.row;
    btnRightW.tag=indexPath.row;
```

it gives only

```
0,0,0,0
 1,1,1,1
 2,2,2,2
 3,3,3,3 
 4,4,4,4
```

Comment: How are u adding the button? Add your code here.

Comment: Is this being done programmatically or on storyboard?

Comment: i ve updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
btnLeftW.tag  = indexPath.row*4 + 1;
btnLeft.tag   = indexPath.row*4 + 2;
btnRight.tag  = indexPath.row*4 + 3;
btnRightW.tag = indexPath.row*4 + 4;
```

Comment: thanks tag value is working good,this is exactly i want,but here the Values changing when i scroll the table View any way to fix this

Comment: IndexPath is always the same value. you can use this to determine other elements