# How to Access Dynamically created UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, iboutlet

Hello everyone i want to implement this concept , i don't know how i can acheive this , whole situation is described in image ,

[image: iDeepak]

Comment: Did you already try something? Like creating buttons programatically, adding layout constraints, setting tags to access them later,...?
Could you share some code please?

Comment: refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820850/how-can-i-set-the-tag-value-for-multiple-buttons-in-a-single-cell-in-tableview-i

Comment: How are these buttons created? You need to provide an example of your current code

Comment: @iDeepak You can use UITableView with custom cell having these buttons and also add, delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to each button and create a variable that would hold the tag of the selected button

when clicking or choosing a button, get its tag and store it to the variable that holds the button tag so that you can then access a button by its tag

```
UIbutton *selectedbutton = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag];
```

Comment: wow thank you for your quick  reply , i will looking for this will try and report you .what about Textfiled  will they also have tag values to access them

Comment: Yes, every object that inherits from UIView will have a `tag` property.

Comment: @Christsooper how to set tag value dynamically , amount of button can be too many , so i don't have to set them manually

Comment: I would advise against using tags, CoN > CoP. Its a loose connection and prone to causing bugs;

Comment: @OliverAtkinson so plz advice better option than this